# Android GridView empty

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

I hope to have a little 'more than lucky and find someone who can help me ...

Let me explain my idea of what I do have a list of strings on the left and right of the screen a list of icons that allow you to perform various operations on strings on the left

This is about the idea that I need.
I thought of various solutions and I think that is a grid that is more close to what I do, all h a problem ... Refine the list of strings, call the GridView ... and I do not print anything on screen, but the screen remains completely empty ...

```
enter code public class TabelleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testo);

    GridView tabella = new GridView (this);
    tabella.setNumColumns(2);

    String[] cols = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, cols);
    tabella.setAdapter(adapter); 
  }
```

Thank you for the patience

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you never add the GridView to the view displayed on screen. To do so, you must call [ViewGroup.addView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method.
For example, you can give an ID to your base layout and do something like :

```
// get the base Layout
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
// add the GridView to it
mainLayout.addView(tabella);
```

Nevertheless, after testing, I reached an IllegalStateException such as :

```
02-22 09:15:13.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Explanation is given by the [official documentation of ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.

So, I need a new resource file to define the item (item.xml). It's like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, I just have to use it in the ArrayAdapter for the GridView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    GridView tabella = new GridView(this);
    tabella.setNumColumns(2);

    String cols[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.item_title, cols);

    tabella.setAdapter(adapter);

    mainLayout.addView(tabella);
}
```

I got the expected behaviour, displaying the GridView. Need some adjustment to suit your needs.